# how long the user took to insert text in my control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

my initial problem is being able to distinguish usual keyboard from a barcodescanner the  idea:
a timer checking if is too fast it must be a barcodescanner,
i tried with event trigger but i could'nt find a way so i end up with some code behind i must also making sure to have the focus on the right control

back end code

```
 private void UiTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
            window.KeyDown += HandleKeyPress;
        }
        private void Windows_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
            NewPrelevementLigne.Focus();
            window.KeyDown += HandleKeyPress;


        }



        private void HandleKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var cle = e.Key;
            var vm = (NewPrelevementVm)this.DataContext;
            vm.LigneAddCommand.Execute(null);
        }
```

my xaml

```
 <wpf:UiTextBlock    Grid.Row="0" Name="NewPrelevementLigne"   Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Texts.NewPrelevementLigne,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontWeight="SemiBold">

                </wpf:UiTextBlock>
```

my command

```
    private RelayCommand _ligneAddCommand;

    public RelayCommand LigneAddCommand => _ligneAddCommand = _ligneAddCommand ?? new RelayCommand(LigneAddKeyDownEventHandle, LignaAddCanBeExecuted);

    protected virtual bool LignaAddCanBeExecuted() => true;

    protected virtual void LigneAddKeyDownEventHandle()
    {
        if (timer != null)
            timer.Stop();

        timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += (s, args) =>
        {
            var t = s.ToString();
            timer.Stop();
        };
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
        timer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by distinguishing this?

Comment: it's for an app that's need an input ,this input can be performed by a user typing on keyboard but he can also use a barcodeScanner i must make the difference because if it is the user he can focus on the right control as there are seveal but for the bacodescanner i will have to fill the other control myself

Comment: I assume that you cannot use Com reader, but must be reader that simulates keyboard. Can you program the reader so that it will give a particular prefix or suffix?

Comment: no i can't because the device could be used by other department

Comment: Don't most barcode scanners add a character to the beginning or end (or both) of the output?  Check the documentation for your scanner.  It may be able to be configured that way.